# Weird optional type behaviour in swift forEach

Tags: swift

This code works fine. It iterates my array of one `Int!` and prints its magnitude.

```
import Foundation

let x : Int! = 1

[x].forEach {i in
    print(i.magnitude)
}
```

Output:

```
1
```

Presumably, `i` in the loop body is an `Int` or an `Int!`, and indeed if I ask Xcode for "quick help" on `forEach` it reports:

```
func forEach(_ body: (Int) throws -> Void) rethrows
```

However, if perform *two* statements in my `forEach` body, instead it fails to compile, complaining that I need to unwrap `i` which now has the optional type `Int?`.

```
import Foundation

let x : Int! = 1

[x].forEach {i in
    print(i.magnitude)
    print(i.magnitude)
}
```

Compile error:

```
Value of optional type 'Int?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'magnitude' of wrapped base type 'Int'
```

And if I ask for "quick help" now I get:

```
func forEach(_ body: (Int?) throws -> Void) rethrows
```

How on earth does the number of statements I place in my loop body manage to affect the type of the loop variable?

Comment: Type inference, plus implicit optionality is not propagated. This is just the price we pay for the way Optionals are baked into the language. You can fix it with explicit typing.

Comment: The compiler has a fast-path for single-expressioned closures. Closures with multiple expressions don't benefit from it, and need explicit type annotation. What you're seeing here is the compiler struggling to infer the types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you've elicited an edge case of an edge case. You've combined two things that are the work of the devil:

- Implicitly unwrapped Optionals
- Implicit type inference of closures, along with the fact that

  - Implicit type inference of closures works differently when the closure consists of one line (this is where the "How on earth does the number of statements" comes in)

You should try to avoid both of those; your code will be cleaner and will compile a *lot* faster. Indeed, implicit type inference of anything other than a single literal, like a string, Int, or Double, is a huge drag on compilation times.

I won't pretend to imitate the compiler's reasoning; I'll just show you an actual solution (other than just not using an IUO in the first place):

```
    [x].forEach {(i:Int) in
        print(i.magnitude)
        print(i.magnitude)
    }
```

Our `Int` type is legal because we take advantage of the single "get out of jail free" card saying that an implicitly unwrapped Optional can be used *directly* where the unwrapped type itself is expected. And by explicitly stating the type, we clear up the compiler's doubts.

(I say "directly" because implicit unwrappedness of an Optional is not propagated thru passing and assignment. That is why in your second example you discovered `Int?`, not `Int`, being passed into the closure.)

Comment: You might be interested in my query at https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-13107 which, if you think about it the right way, is actually related to this situation.

Comment: Great answer! To clarify something: in the non-example version of this code, the array is of storyboard `IBOutlets` (which xcode creates as implicitly unwrapped optionals for sensible enough reasons). That makes avoiding your first bullet point not my choice!

Comment: Curious: does `{ (i:Int) in ... }` have the effect of implying `-> Void` (as happens with bare functions like `func f() { ... }`), or does it leave the return type unspecified and thus, require inference?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica It is known from the declaration of `forEach`.

Comment: @JamieCockburn Whether outlets should be IUOs is a religious war.

Comment: @matt Yes, but I'm curious about the general case (imagine the call was to `map` instead, which expects a yet-unknown generic `T` to be returned). Just played around with it, and got some curious findings. Suppose instead of `print`, the calls were to some function `p(_: Any) -> String` (which say, prints, but then also returns the string value). Calling with one expr implicitly returns it, making the result type inferred to `[String]`. If you call it twice, there's no longer an implicit return of the string expr, and instead an implicit `return ()`, so `[()]` is inferred.

Comment: @matt That's interesting, so it looks like `{ (i:Int) in ... }` has the effect of fixing the argument type, but not the return value (so it's still inferred), which differs from the `fucn` syntax, where it fixes the arg type and implies the return value (`-> Void`), too. Interesting.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I don’t know what you mean by general. `map` doesn’t return Void. That is unrelated to this situation where the return type is declared already. For `map` you have to give the parameter type and the return type somehow. See the bugs.swift link I cited earlier.

Comment: Read that bug, interesting but not related. I'm on a little tangent about the specific semantics of explicitly specifying some parts of a closure's type (the arg type), but not others (the return type). By "general case" I meant: a case where the inference can't just pin down the value of the closure's return type from signature (like with `forEach`, where it's always `Void`). I cite `map` as an example. Take `let result = [1, 2, 3].map { (i: Int) in p(i.magnitude) }`. The type of `result` isn't determined, so the only type info about the closure comes from the closure itself.

Comment: The type of `result` is `[String]` if `p` is only called once (because that one fn call expr is implicitly returned, thereby determining the return type of the closure as `String`). The return type of `result` is `[Void]` if `p` is called twice (because neither fn call expr is implicitly returned, instead `return Void` implied upon reaching the end of the closure). So that answered my question: "it looks like `{ (i:Int) in ... }` has the effect of fixing the argument type, but not the return value (so it's still inferred), unlike the `func` syntax, where `-> Void` is implied if unspecified